# why is AccessDenied returned for only some images in an S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Carrierwave in a Rails app to upload image files to S3.

This has been working perfectly for some time.

Suddenly newly uploaded files are returning "AccessDenied". This only occurs when accessing the file via Cloudfront CDN references. If the direct S3 url is used, the image displays correctly.

I have an access policy and permissions set on the S3 bucket.

What is confusing me is why some files are returning Access Denied, whilst others are displaying correctly.

Examining the properties in S3, all files have the same permissions and policies, which are set at the bucket level.

What per-file settings can be set on S3 that would cause only some files to return Access Denied? And how are those settings configured?

Comment: Can you verify that you are setting the permissions on the actual records and not just on the bucket?  IE record.acl     = :public_read before you call record.save

Comment: thanks @ruby_newbie. I should be setting public_read, via Carrierwave's  `config.fog_public` setting. However it may be that this is not being called correctly. How can I verify this from the S3 console. Does this change the view/edit/list permissions? If so, then yes, all records have the same permissions.

Comment: Observe the response headers from CloudFront.  Do you see `X-Cache: hit from cloudfront` or is it `X-Cache: miss from cloudfront`? The former means the object is cached, the latter means not.  You may also see `X-Cache: error from cloudfront` and an error should be accompanied by an `Age:` header if it's a cached error. Cache hits also have `Age:`; in both cases, this is a time in seconds since the origin (S3) was contacted. You may have cached the errors or cached the successes, and in fact all requests that are not from cache are either working or not working. Is there a pattern?

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I am getting `X-Cache: Error from cloudfront` for the Access Denied files, whereas other files are `hit from cloudfront`. How can I determine the cause of the error?